# Memory data source for Better player plugin flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-video-player

I am building an app where users can post images or videos. I am having trouble finding the best way to display the videos. I have tried using the flutter teams video player plugin but I don't want to have to save the video as a file in order to display it. I was hoping for something similar to the Image.memory() constructor. I have since then switched to the Better_Player plugin which has a memory constructor. However, I have not been able to get it to work correctly. For me it just shows a black screen and doesn't display the video. Here is the code for displaying the video.

```dart
BetterPlayerListVideoPlayer(
    BetterPlayerDataSource(
        BetterPlayerDataSourceType.MEMORY,
            "",
            bytes: widget.videoData.toList(),
     ),
            configuration: BetterPlayerConfiguration(
             looping: true,
              aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
              autoPlay: false,
              controlsConfiguration: BetterPlayerControlsConfiguration(
                enableOverflowMenu: false,
                showControlsOnInitialize: false,
              ),
            ),
            autoPlay: false,
          )
```

[Image of output from better_player plugin claiming the data source is of file type when I am using memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvOM7.png)

I am unsure if I am using the data source correctly. I am passing an array of bytes that is coming from a base64 decoded string. Thanks for any insights. Right now I am just sending the full video as a base64 encoded string from the server. If anyone knows the best practices or a better way to do this please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when trying to run BetterPlayer from memory. I solved it by defining the additional parameter `videoExtension` as "mp4".